# не срабатывает псевдокласс :not(:first-child)

Tags: html, css, классы

Есть простая структура с дочерними p. Не срабатывает псевдокласс :not(:first-child). Когда из данного контейнера убираю тег img, то все работает. Непонятно, почему не срабатывает, ведь обращение вот такое - .header_feedback_block_tel p:not(:first-child).

```css
.header_feedback_block_tel p {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
}

.header_feedback_block_tel p:not(:first-child) {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_feedback_block_tel">
  <img src="">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому, что первый потомок (`:first-child`) у вас это как раз `<img>`, а первого потомка `p` не существует. Чтобы срабатывало на определённый тег используйте `:first-of-type` :

```css
.header_feedback_block_tel p {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
}

.header_feedback_block_tel p:not(:first-of-type) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_feedback_block_tel">
  <img src="">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: «Век живи – век учись». Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, первым у тебя был `img`, а не `p`; а во-вторых, можно вообще заменить на плюс:

```css
.header_feedback_block_tel p {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
}

.header_feedback_block_tel p + p {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_feedback_block_tel">
  <img src="">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Интересное решение.